# Why does someone wanting to get married need to show an Orthodox ketubah from a maternal ancestor?

Tags: marriage, rabbis, heterodox, orthodox

My friend is due to get married soon and has been asked by her Orthodox Rabbi to provide proof that she is jewish by showing that she is descended from jews.  She doesn't have her parents Ketubah so the Rabbi said that she could provide evidence that her maternal grandparents had a jewish wedding as evidence instead.

She has looked and her grandparents seem to have been married by a Conservative Rabbi. Her Rabbi said that this wasn't good enough as the wedding had to be Orthodox to be accepted. Apparently this is also the view of the central beth din.  This means she can't have an Orthodox wedding according to at least one country's rules of Orthodox judaism.

What I don't understand is that Conservative, Reform, Orthodox etc. judaism didn't exist as a concept before the 19th century so presumably if you look far back enough, all jews are descended from the same groups of people.  And it seems clear that if my friend could establish that her maternal great-grandmother, say, was Orthodox that would do no matter what her grandparents practised. So what is the distinction that today's Orthodox jews are trying to make? It doesn't make sense to me.

Are Orthodox jews  worried that someone in her maternal ancestry might have converted to Conservative Judaism (see e.g. http://judaism.about.com/od/conversion/f/consconv_accept.htm) and so she would not count as a jew at all in their eyes if that had happened? Or are they worried that non-Orthodox Rabbis would allow intermarriage (see e.g. http://forward.com/articles/142112/conservative-synagogues-crack-open-door-to-interma/) and so the wife might not have been jewish at all?

Comment: This whole scenario as presented doesn't make sense to me. There must be information we are lacking. Are there any converts on her maternal line? Is she marrying a Cohen?

Comment: Also, the question (which is unclear) doesn't match the title. Consider editing to bring them into sync.

Comment: @yoel Why doesn't it make sense? She doesn't have her parents' ketubah so they want evidence from her grandparents. Is this not common?  She is not marrying a Cohen.  The title is a little provocative just to make the point that I don't understand what the difference is if you are looking at someone's full jewish ancestry.

Comment: If you are asking us to explain what a certain rabbi said to your friend, you are going to have to be more precise in what happened.

Comment: felipa, welcome to Mi Yodeya! I think that in order for the community here to help you understand the basis for this rabbi's requirements, it'd be necessary to [edit] into the question precisely what the rabbi said to your friend, and all of the relevant circumstances. Between what your friend told you and what you've written here, it's possible that some incorrect assumptions are included, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: I am trying to understand what Orthodox jews really want when they ask for evidence that you are descended from Orthodox jews.  The only thing I can guess is that maybe they are worried that a maternal  ancestor converted to Conservative judaism and so isn't in their eyes really a jew at all.

Comment: IsaacMoses. Hello. I don't think I missed anything out but if there is anything I can clarify, would you mind pointing that out to me?

Comment: Did the rabbi actually say "please prove that you're descended from Orthodox Jews," or is that your friend's or your interpretation of what he said? Unless this is part of some documented standard process, it's really hard for anyone but that rabbi to explain what his concerns were in this situation.

Comment: One reason that I suspect that something is missing from this story is that Jews who come from non-Orthodox families become Orthodox and get married under Orthodox auspices all the time.

Comment: @IsaacMoses (See edited question) The Rabbi asked for proof of her judaism. This seems normal to me. She asked how she could prove this as she has no paperwork from her parents and he said that evidence of an Orthodox wedding of her maternal grandparents would do.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Do you mean they convert or they are simply allowed to marry Orthodox men and be accepted immediately?

Comment: If someone is born to a Jewish mother, regardless of her affiliation or observance, that person is 100% Jewish and allowed to marry another Jew. There is no conversion involved. I guess that this rabbi, in this situation, wants documentation that demonstrates that your friend's mother, and therefore your friend, is indeed Jewish. There are various ways this could be documented, one of which would be a ketuba produced by a previous rabbi who would likewise have checked. If the current rabbi trusts that the previous rabbi would have checked as a prerequesite to officiating, then he's all set.

Comment: Without knowing the entirety of the situation, I can't tell why the rabbi wants this documentation in this case. However, I strongly suspect that he's not trying to prove that your friend's forebears were Orthodox, but that they were Jewish, with an Orthodox-produced ketuba being a potential method for this.

Comment: @IsaacMoses (See edited question again.) My guess is that they don't accept people who have converted to non-Orthodox judaism and maybe also that they don't trust non-Orthodox jews not to allow marriages between jews and non-jews.

Comment: Felipa, your guess is as good as any of ours. Why are you asking a totally random group of anonymous people to guess at why a totally random anonymous rabbi wanted from a totally random anonymous person none of us has met?

Comment: @SethJ If this is not a universal rule for Orthodox judaism then that is interesting. The central beth din apparently also holds the line that a Conservative ketubah is not sufficient evidence. So it's not just one Rabbi.

Comment: Felipa, that's the first piece of useful information you've provided. Clearly, then, it is a policy of the Beth Din. Now you have someplace to go for answers.

Comment: felipa, I agree with @Seth that the central beth din you're referring to is probably the best place to go for clarification of its and its rabbis' policies. In addition, if you can identify which beth din it is in the question, there may be someone here who's familiar enough with it to answer specifically regarding its policies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Conservative kesuba can be suspect. As noted in Rabbi Emanuel Feldman's book, "Tales Out of Shul," as a young Orthodox rabbi in Atlanta in the 1960s, he was under tremendous pressure by wealthy members to do a quicky conversion to the member's child's non-Jewish fiancee. He would refuse, and those members would leave the shul and join a Conservative shul, making large donations, and getting what they wanted. The result was that Jews were married to non-Jews who were not sincere converts. That is reason for great concern.

Answer (score 13):

If someone is born to a Jewish mother, regardless of her affiliation or observance, that person [is 100% Jewish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_is_a_jew#Halakhic_perspective) and allowed to marry another Jew. There is no conversion involved. I guess that this rabbi, in this situation, wants documentation that demonstrates that your friend's mother, and therefore your friend, is indeed Jewish. There are various ways this could be documented, one of which would be a ketuba produced by a previous rabbi who would likewise have checked. If the current rabbi trusts that the previous rabbi would have checked as a prerequesite to officiating, then he's all set.

Without knowing the entirety of the situation, I can't tell why the rabbi wants this documentation in this case. However, I strongly suspect that he's not trying to prove that your friend's forebears were Orthodox, but that they were Jewish, with an Orthodox-produced ketuba being a potential method for this.

There are various possible reasons why the current rabbi wouldn't consider a Conservative-produced ketuba, by itself, as proof that the participants were Jewish. As you suggest, he may be concerned about forebears who may have been born non-Jewish and converted according to Conservative standards, or he may just be concerned that the previous rabbi wouldn't have checked into the situation with the same rigor that he would.

It would probably be worthwhile for your friend to discuss the particular situation in depth with the rabbi to discover what his particular concerns are and how they may be met.

Comment: Thanks for this.  So it seems that at least this Orthodox Rabbi (and apparently the central beth din) doesn't accept a Conservative ketubah and so won't allow someone with only this evidence to have an Orthodox wedding. As a result my friend can't have children who will be accepted as jews by the Orthodox community either it seems.  For me that is the same as their saying that a Conservative jew is not a jew at all which rather contradicts http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_is_a_jew#Halakhic_perspective in practice. I also can't believe this important question has been downvoted three times!

Comment: It is worth noting that the Israeli Rabbinate requires all immigrants to provide documentation of Jewish heritage in order to register to marry in Israel. This is regardless of religious affiliation. For example, as someone who is (and looks) orthodox, I was still asked to provide my parent's ketubah to register. I also had to provide two witnesses that testified that I remained Jewish while living in America. This is standard operating procedure (and many in Israel want to fix these premises), but it is not an issue of being identified with Conservative/Reform Judaism.

Comment: @Aryeh That's interesting. So the Israeli Rabbinate will accept a non-Orthodox ketubah where the Orthodox beth din in my country won't it seems.

Comment: @Aryeh But if you want to avoid the hassle and bureaucracy of the Rabbanut, you can just get married with the Eidah haChareidis. Despite people's perceptions, they are efficient, easy to deal with, and they don't bother with all the paperwork.

Comment: @felipa, like I said in a comment on the question, in my experience, people who come from non-Orthodox backgrounds get married under Orthodox auspices all the time. I would be surprised if your friend and the rabbinate she's dealing with couldn't work together to find some evidence of her Jewish status that's acceptable to them (assuming, of course, that she is indeed Halachicly Jewish).

Comment: @Curiouser That's very interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @felipa, every Jewish institution requests evidence of their members' Jewishness. My synagogue wanted to know the name of the rabbi who married my parents. IMO, if your question had been asked regarding general religious law, or even policies of the Batei Din in your country, the question would not have been voted down. It comes off as a nasty slur against all of Orthodoxy, hence my downvote and vote to close.

Comment: @felipa, a Conservative synagogue in which I once worked also demanded proof of Jewishness for all of their members, their Hebrew school students, and any couples who wanted to get married by their rabbi(s). Care to guess what was the best evidence that they would accept?

Comment: @felipa: A Conservative kesuba can be suspect.  As noted in Rabbi Emanuel Feldman's book, "Tales Out of Shul," as a young Orthodox rabbi in Atlanta in the 1960s, he was under tremendous pressure by wealthy members to do a quicky conversion to the member's child's non-Jewish fiancee.  He would refuse, and those members would leave the shul and join a Conservative shul, making large donations, and getting what they wanted.  The result was that Jews were married to non-Jews who were not sincere converts.  That is reason for great concern.

Comment: @BruceJames Thanks. That's very useful. Could you put it as an answer?

Comment: @SethJ No slur intended.  I think judaism is robust enough to cope with questions from all fours sons.

Comment: @felipa "*So the Israeli Rabbinate will accept a non-Orthodox ketubah...*" I think you misread Aryeh's comment. "Regardless of religious affiliation" refers to the person not the documentation.

Comment: @Fred I am assuming a non-orthodox person is likely to have non-orthodox documentation.

Comment: @felipa It's not uncommon for a non-Orthodox Jew to have parents or grandparents with an Orthodox ketubah. Regardless, I assume there are some other ways for a non-Orthodox Jew to demonstrate that they are Jewish by Orthodox standards aside from showing a *ketubah*. But if a person wants to use a *ketubah* as proof, only an Orthodox one will satisfy the burden of evidence from the standpoint of the Orthodox *beit din* (for reasons mentioned in this answer).

Comment: @Fred Thanks. The sticking point here is what these "other ways for a non-Orthodox Jew to demonstrate that they are Jewish by Orthodox standards" could be. But that is perhaps a topic for another question.

Comment: @felipa, a question along the lines of "What forms of evidence do batei din accept to establish that someone is Jewish?" would indeed be a useful question to post.