# Questions about marriage, life, Judaism as a BT who grew up reform?

Tags: marriage, ketubah

I Grew up as a reform Jew but I became more religious my parents were never married and don't have a Ketubah. I also do not have ketubah  for my grandparents, what will happen how can I get married? Am I allowed to get married?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya. This, unfortunately, is not the place to ask [this kind of question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734). This question in particular needs to be addressed by a professional Rabbi who you can speak to in person and discuss with. We hope this doesn't put you off asking and answering other questions with us in future! Hatzlacha (be successful)

Comment: To my understanding, a ketubah from your parents is only possibly required to verify your Jewish identity but has no other need for getting married.

Comment: @Growing this site doesn't provide personalized advice the way an Orthodox rabbi can, but do check out this answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/132637/can-a-jew-who-grew-up-conservative-have-an-orthodox-wedding